# Submitting search form but also having query string in PHP (and JS)

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I have a page with a search form (with just one field) submitting to another page to perform a search and show results.

Often on other sites whenever I search for something in a form I see my search terms in a query string which is handy for bookmarking/sharing a link with someone.

eg-

```
 http://grooveshark.com/#/search?q=name+of+band
```

How is the query string made from a form submission?

Comment: Please note that this hash (#) or hash bang (#!) type of URL is considered to be a hack. Albeit a hack used by Google and Twitter. HTML5 session history should alleviate the need for this kind of thing. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/history.html Also, do you need it in this case? Why not just use a standard query string?

Comment: I've not really looked into HTML5 and session history so didn't know about it, but the only reason I can see myself using my way is for bookmarks/sending links to other people.

Comment: You don't need to use a # in the URL to achieve this unless your site is written mostly in Javascript, make sure you understand what a # in a URL is.

Comment: Ah.. I misunderstood you. I hadn't really paid attention to them and as I only seem to pick things up as I need them for my projects I hadn't come across them. A little research does show they're not recommended though, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your form to use the get method instead of post, or add the attribute below if it's not there already.

`<form name="test" action="some/page.php" method="get">`

Comment: Seems so obvious! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

The query string is constructed by the user agent by processing the form data. You can read more about it [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13).

Comment: Thanks, interesting to look at.